# How to insert a \vline inside a matrix node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have to draw many nodes inside a rectangle and separate the first one from the following ones with a line. 
It seems to work if I do it vertically: I use a matrix node for the outer rectangle and draw the nodes inside separating them with a \hline

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner sep = 1pt, rectangle,matrix,ampersand replacement=\&] (A)
     {\node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {a }; \\ \hline \\ \node {$d_1$};\\ \node {$\vdots$};\\ \node{$d_n$};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, when I try to do the same thing horizontally the \vline doesn't display:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner sep = 1pt, rectangle,matrix,ampersand replacement=\&] (A)
     {\node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {a}; \& \vline \& \node {$d_1$};\& \node {$\dots$};\& \node{$d_n$};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Any idea why?

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner sep = 1pt, rectangle,matrix,ampersand replacement=\&] 
    (A) {\node[inner sep= 2pt] (a) {a }; \\ \hline \\ \node {$d_1$};\\ \node {$\vdots$};\\ \node{$d_n$};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\bigskip


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, inner sep = 1pt, rectangle,matrix,ampersand replacement=\&] (A)
     {\node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {a}; \& \vline \& \node {$d_1$};\& \node {$\dots$};\& \node{$d_n$};\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first example does not work for me. Could you please give us a compilable but minimal example of your document?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi you are right. First of all there was a missing "]".
Also, I found out that it is relevant that the document class is beamer. Using the class minimal none of the two example work (they compile but both the \hline and the \vline are not displaying).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example sets the vertical line in three variants:

- A dummy node is placed to save some space and to get the horizontal position.
  Then the largest element is named `dn` for the vertical positions. Afterwards
  a line is drawn.
- The line can be extended to the frame, when the `inner sep` is added to the bottom and top.
- The line is simply drawn as math symbol `|`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      draw,
      inner sep = 1pt,
      rectangle,
      matrix,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] (A) {%
      \node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {a }; \\
      \hline \\
      \node {$d_1$};\\
      \node[rotate=90, inner sep=2pt] {$\dots$};\\
      \node{$d_n$};\\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      draw,
      inner sep = 1pt,
      rectangle,
      matrix,
      anchor=base,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] (A) {%
      \node (a) {a}; \&
      \node (vline) {}; \&
      \node {$d_1$};\&
      \node {$\dots$};\&
      \node (dn) {$d_n$};\\
    };
    \draw (vline |- dn.south) -- (vline |- dn.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      draw,
      inner sep = 1pt,
      rectangle,
      matrix,
      anchor=base,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] (A) {%
      \node (a) {a}; \&
      \node[inner sep=0pt] {$|$}; \&
      \node {$d_1$};\&
      \node {$\cdots$};\&
      \node {$d_n$};\\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Hints:**

- The nodes are vertically centered, thus the `a` does not have the same baseline as `d` with subscripts. This can be fixed by adding `anchor=base` to the matrix options.
- It is correct that `a` is not set in math as `d`?
- `\vdots` are not symmetrically in the vertical direction. Therefore the example replaced them with rotated `\dots`.
- The latest version uses `\cdots`, for the case the dots should not be on the baseline.

### TikZ library `matrix`

The TikZ library `matrix` provides  key `matrix of nodes`, which allows a more compact representation of the matrices. The example uses `\midrule` of package `booktabs`, because it adds some space around the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      inner sep=1pt,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] {
      a \\
      \midrule
      $d_1$ \\
      |[rotate=90, inner sep=2pt]| $\dots$ \\
      $d_n$ \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      inner sep=1pt,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] {
      a \&
      |[inner sep=0pt]| $|$ \&
      $d_1$ \&
      $\dots$ \&
      $d_n$ \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result matrix of nodes]

Or both with drawn lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (tmp) [
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      inner sep=1pt,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] {
      a \\[4pt]
      $d_1$ \\
      |[rotate=90, inner sep=2pt]| $\dots$ \\
      $d_n$ \\
    };
    \draw
      ($(tmp.west |- tmp-1-1.south) + (1pt, -2pt)$) --
      ($(tmp.east |- tmp-1-1.south) + (-1pt, -2pt)$)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (tmp) [
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      inner sep=1pt,
      ampersand replacement=\&,
    ] {
      a \&
      |[inner sep=0pt]| \kern2pt \&
      $d_1$ \&
      $\dots$ \&
      $d_n$ \\
    };
    \draw
      ($(tmp-1-2 |- tmp.south) + (0pt, 1pt)$) --
      ($(tmp-1-2 |- tmp.north) + (0pt, -1pt)$)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

[image]

or you prefer, that line stick with border of node? Above image is generated by

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               prewiev]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,inner sep = 1pt,rectangle, matrix, ampersand replacement=\&] (A)
     {\node[inner sep=2pt] (a) {a}; 
      \& \& \node {$d_1$};
      \& \node {$\dots$};
      \& \node{$d_n$};\\};
\draw (a.north east) -- (a.south east);% <--- this is new
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:**
An alternative, more simple (to my opinion) solution can be achieved by following code:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,many,
               prewiev]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw,inner sep=1pt,matrix of math nodes] (m) 
        {
a & d_1 & \dots & d_n\\
        };
\draw (m-1-2.north west) -- (m-1-2.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

It gives similar but slightly nicer result as show image above.

Comment: This works, thanks!
I guess it would still be interesting to know why \hline works but \vline doesn't.

Comment: @claudia, I edit my answer: add a simple MWE to write a horizontal vector (one row matrices), which can compete with (excellent) accepted answer. I had a lot of fun with play (read: search for simple solution) for your question. Have a nice day!